# Is it mandatory to specify minSdkVersion and targetSdkVerion

Tags: android, android-manifest

My app was working on galaxy s1, s2 and galaxy TAB but my client found it not working on galaxy s3.
Via on-line testing I found it not working on nexus too

In my manifest it was specified

```
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```

I tried to explore the problem and I found that I should specify in manifest

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
      android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Kindly guide me what exactly should I need to do to make it work on all devices !
Help is always appreciated *_*

Comment: By not working, you mean it is crashing on the s3?

Comment: if it crashing then there some error in your code .show your code please . SHow logcat message from s3 device

Comment: I had a galaxy s3 I would be able to remove it myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:minSdkVersion
```

An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

**Caution:** If you do not declare this attribute, the system assumes a default value of "1", which indicates that your application is compatible with all versions of Android. If your application is not compatible with all versions (for instance, it uses APIs introduced in API Level 3) and you have not declared the proper minSdkVersion, then when installed on a system with an API Level less than 3, the application will crash during runtime when attempting to access the unavailable APIs. For this reason, be certain to declare the appropriate API Level in the minSdkVersion attribute.

```
android:targetSdkVersion
```

This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion).

An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 1):

Its mandatory. it indictes the minimum android version needed to install and run that application. if it is not present, it causes error.